# Evento "append" no carregamento da página

Tags: jquery

Nesse trecho de código, a `div1` é posicionada na `div2` quando se clica nela, mas eu queria que isso fosse feita de forma automática no carregamento da página sem que seja necessário clicar nela.

Já tentei substituit o evento .click por .load ou .ready mas não dá.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#DIV1').click(function () {

        $('#DIV2').append(this);

    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve fazer assim:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#DIV2').append($('#DIV1'));
});
```

No código que tinha, `this` era um ponteiro para o elemento clicado, ou seja `$('#DIV1')`. E quando o clic surgia a div2 recebia por append o `this`.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Quebrei tanto a cabeça com isso já. Funcionando certinho!